# What is the point of the redeem tab in Fallout Shelter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

In Fallout Shelter there is a tab in the lunchbox section titled "redeem". I was wondering where or how I get things to redeem for it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When the game first launched, there were free lunchbox codes distributed various ways that you could redeem. I got an email newsletter from Bethesda (for example) which contained one. Not sure what other distribution methods there were, or if any of those promotions are ongoing.

Comment: I see. Too bad I missed out! Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roddy of the Frozen Wastes commented:

> When the game first launched, there were free lunchbox codes distributed various ways that you could redeem. I got an email newsletter from Bethesda (for example) which contained one. Not sure what other distribution methods there were, or if any of those promotions are ongoing.

You still might be able to find lunchbox, pet carrier, or Mr. Handy codes floating around the internet. If you have of one of these codes you can redeem it for a reward.